# Calling a function name inside a function in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have tried to call the two method inside the function where I couldn't able to call those method. I have tried few approaches but not succeeded. Here, What I have tried

"UserStartShift", "UserStopShift" are the API functions which have GET and POST method in it. These API are working fine individually, I wanted to return a different response using the conditional statement.

views.py:

```
# startshift
@api_view(['GET']) 
def UserStartShift(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
     
               UserId = request.data.get('UserId')
               Ip = request.data.get('Ip')
               PortNumber = request.data.get('PortNumber')
               print("UserId-->", UserId)
               print("Ip-->", Ip)
               print('Portnumber-->', PortNumber)


               cursor = connection.cursor()
               cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[Usp_StartShift]  @UserId=%s, @IP=%s, @Port=%s', (UserId,  Ip, PortNumber,))
     
               return Response(True, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


# endshift
@api_view(['GET']) 
def UserStopShift(request, UserId):
    try:
        users = tblUserShiftDetails.objects.filter(UserId=UserId)
    except tblUserShiftDetails.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_StopShift] @UserId=%s',(UserId,))
       
        return Response(True)
     
        



#UserShiftDetailsView
     @api_view(['GET'])
    def UserShiftDetailsView(request, userid):
    
        try:
            users = tblUserShiftDetails.objects.filter(UserId=userid)
        except tblUserShiftDetails.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
        if request.method == 'GET':
    
            if UserStartShift == True: 
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCurrentShiftDetails] @UserId=%s',(userid,))
                result_set = cursor.fetchall()
             
                for row in result_set:
                    row = row[0]
                return Response({"IsStarted":True,"EstimatedShifEnd":(row + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M  %p'),"ReasonforAccess": "null"})
          
            elif UserStopShift == True :
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCurrentShiftDetails] @UserId=%s',(userid,))
                result_set = cursor.fetchall()
              
                for row in result_set:
                    row = row[0]
                return Response({"IsStarted":False,"EstimatedShifEnd":"null","ReasonforAccess": "null"})
```

Comment: `if request.method == 'GET' or request.method=="POST":` may be this could help you, have you tried this one ?

Comment: From what is UserStartShift and UserStopShift coming from? Where do you set them = True? Anyways, you set a decorator that allows only GET for that view. POST won't work.

Comment: UserStartShift and UserStopShift these are the API function which I have created whenever the user starts the shift it will return the response same applies for the stop shift as well I have edited the code for the better understanding.